# what is difference between (**) and (<<) in python?

Tags: python, bit-shift, exponent

```
a = 100000000
c = (2**(a-1))-1
b = (2<<(a-1))-1
m = 1000000007
print b%m
print c%m
```

Output :

```
494499947
247249973
```

I am using ** and << operator in python to find powers of 2 raised to a very large number . However similar operations give different result. Just curious why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2**4 = 2^4 = 2*2*2*2

```
>>> 2**4 
16
```

2<<4 = Shift left 4 bits:
Before shift, 2 is 10 in binary; After shift, 2 is 100000 in binary

```
>>> 2<<4 
32
```

Comment: `>>> 2**4 // 2^4` outputs 12, you meant `#` instead of `//` I suppose :)

Answer (score 12):

`**` is the exponent operator. `<<` shifts bits to the left.

Because of the nature of binary numbers, for ever step shifting bits to the left doubles the number. As such you can express the same operation as 2 to the power number-of-shifts minus one:

```
>>> 1 << 1  # 00000001 becomes 0000010
2
>>> 1 << 2  # 00000001 becomes 0000100
4
>>> 1 << 15 # 000000000000001 becomes 1000000000000000
32768
```

The exponent operator serves to produce exponents of more than just the number 2, however:

```
>>> 3 ** 3
27
```

Note however that `2 ** 1` is still two, but shifting to once to the left (`2 << 1`) is equivalent to `2 ** 2`:

```
>>> 2 ** 1
2
>>> 2 << 1
4
```

Answer (score 12):

The results are different because the equivalent of `2 ** n` is `1 << n`, not `2 << n`.

Comment: although it __is__ equal to `2 << (n-1)`

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` operator means left shift. It is not the same as power of two, although it can be used to compute it.

As an example:

```
0b10101 << 1 ==> 0b101010
0b1000  >> 1 ==> 0b100
0b10    << 2 ==> 0b1000
```

To use left shift-operation to compute the power of two you can define a function like this:

```
def poweroftwo(x):
    return 1 << x
```